# How to execute query as specific user in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to execute a query like

```
select count(*) from some_table;
```

as a specific user when logged in as a database "super user" like sys or sysadmin?

How can this be accomplished?

**UPDATE**

we have where clauses like this:

```
where column_user_name=user
```

So the DB needs to think the current user as specified by `user` is the user we want to pretend to be.

Comment: Where do you have the `WHERE` clause?  Are you talking about a VPD function?  Or a user-defined view that adds the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: In our case it's a user defined view, but the point is the same... I would like `user` to return the user we are "acting as" instead of the db admin user that we initially logged in as.

Comment: I'm looking for something akin to Unix `su`.  Something that allows the db admins to switch to any user and then act as that user for the remainder of the session.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your question correctly, it should be possible with

```
alter session set current_schema = <username>;
```

and then running your statement.

**Update** Your new requirement (`where x = USER`) does not work with this approach (as you have already figured out). However, you can change `user` to `sys_context('userenv', 'current_schema')` which will return the name of altered schema.

Comment: The query needs to be executed as the specified user, not just on the specified user's schema.  We have where clauses like this `where column_user_name=user`

Answer (score 4):

You can, but you'd need to use an undocumented package to do so.  The [`dbms_sys_sql` package lets you run SQL as another user](https://blog.pythian.com/using-dbms_sys_sql-to-execute-statements-as-another-user/).  That's something that Application Express (APEX) uses internally.  But it's undocumented so you'd use it at your own risk.

In general, you ought not be connecting to a database as `SYS` during normal day-to-day operations.  If you're a DBA (using your own account, not `SYS`), you ought to be able to query from any user's table because you'd have the `SELECT ANY TABLE` privilege.  So you ought to be able to run

```
SELECT *
  FROM some_user.some_table_name
```

Comment: the `some_user.some_table_name` won't work... see update in question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Proxy User Authentication:

```
SQL> CONNECT/@mytnsname AS SYSDBA
Connected.
SQL> CREATE USER user_impersonating IDENTIFIED BY password1;

User created.

SQL> CREATE USER user_being_impersonated IDENTIFIED BY password2;

User created.

SQL> GRANT CONNECT TO user_impersonating;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CONNECT TO user_being_impersonated;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> ALTER USER user_being_impersonated GRANT CONNECT THROUGH user_impersonating;

User altered.

SQL> DISCONNECT;
Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
SQL> CONNECT user_impersonating[user_being_impersonated]/password1@mytnsname
Connected.
SQL> SELECT user FROM DUAL;

USER
------------------------------
USER_BEING_IMPERSONATED

SQL> SHOW USER
USER is "USER_BEING_IMPERSONATED"
SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the proxy:
alter user order_request  grant connect through system;
connect system
[order_request]/cidw_pre